# Publishing PostGIS layer with EPSG:5514 not working in GeoServer of version 2.16.2

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I can not using EPSG: 5514 for publishing layers. Data was stored in PostGIS.

GeoServer returns this error:

> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of
>   interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at
>   org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1@6237d421 on
>   component [AjaxSubmitLink [Component id = computeNative]] threw an
>   exception
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1324.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/geotools/filter/function/FilterFunction_arrayAnyMatch     at
>   org.geotools.data.postgis.FilterToSqlHelper.createFilterCapabilities(FilterToSqlHelper.java:186)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisFilterToSQL.createFilterCapabilities(PostgisFilterToSQL.java:100)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQL.getCapabilities(FilterToSQL.java:431)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getFilterCapabilities(JDBCDataStore.java:541)
>     at org.geotools.jdbc.SQLDialect.splitFilter(SQLDialect.java:1281)   at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.splitFilter(JDBCFeatureSource.java:378)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.splitFilter(JDBCFeatureSource.java:365)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:464)
>     at
>   org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureStore.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureStore.java:181)
>     at
>   org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getBounds(ContentFeatureSource.java:413)

[image: Error info]

How can I resolve this problem?

Geoserver logs contains next error:

> Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
>   already. Could not load

Table description:

[image]

I tried other table with EPSG: 3857 and problem is same.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what you table schema looks like (what types of columns do you have)? Why you think the projection is an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve problem. Reinstalled Geoserver without [BackupRestore](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.16.x/community-latest/geoserver-2.16-SNAPSHOT-backup-restore-plugin.zip) running correctly